# R Shiny -- Using "predict" with user input

Tags: r, shiny

In my Shiny app, I currently am loading an .RData file and displaying the different linear models saved in the .RData file in a drop-down selector input. The user can select something, and I can print out what they selected, similar to the Shiny tutorial.

I want to use the user-selected linear model with the predict function. Currently my code is:

```
output$plot2 <-
renderPlot(plot(predict(input$choose_data,Test[-c(21, 22, 17, 10, 5, 6,
                                                    11, 2, 26)]),
                  Test$WAR,main = "Predicted v. Actual"))
```

The error I get is:

> Error: no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "character"

If I replace `input$choose_data` with the name of a linear model, the plot outputs correctly. Additionally, I have printed out `input$choose_data` to show that it is selecting the correct linear model.

So I need to convert `input$choose_data` from just a string to the actual saved linear model object. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: It is possible that from your `UI.r` where user selects the model, it is just passing model name to the `predict` function  and not data  in `Server.r`?

Comment: get(input$choose_data) worked!